# How to generate dynamic richtext in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, richtext

I have a comment widget in my flutter and this widget also includes mention or hashgh in the comment message. I want to find mentions in the comment message and make them clickable and in different colors, the same will be true for hashgh.

```
   commentMessage: 'Hi @Brad Pitt are u so cute #socute @Jackie Chan',
   mentionList: ['@Brad Pitt', '@Jackie Chan'],
   hastaghList: ['#socute'],
```

How should I proceed with what I have?

Answer (score 0):

look bro, first you gotta make a function that parses the text into a list that contains the text and its type of text, i made this parser that could be the starting point for the rich texts, once you have this List its a matter of mapping the list to its corresponding RichText TextStyle

```
enum TextType { normal, mention, hashtag }

class TextContent {
  String text;
  TextType type;

  TextContent(this.text, this.type);
}

List<TextContent> parseText(String input) {
  List<TextContent> textContents = [];

  RegExp mentionPattern = RegExp(r"@(\w+)");
  RegExp hashtagPattern = RegExp(r"#(\w+)");

  int currentIndex = 0;

  mentionPattern.allMatches(input).forEach((match) {
    int start = match.start;
    int end = match.end;

    if (start > currentIndex) {
      String normalText = input.substring(currentIndex, start);
      textContents.add(TextContent(normalText, TextType.normal));
    }

    String mentionText = input.substring(start, end);
    textContents.add(TextContent(mentionText, TextType.mention));

    currentIndex = end;
  });

  if (currentIndex < input.length) {
    String remainingText = input.substring(currentIndex);
    textContents.add(TextContent(remainingText, TextType.normal));
  }

  hashtagPattern.allMatches(input).forEach((match) {
    int start = match.start;
    int end = match.end;

    String hashtagText = input.substring(start, end);
    textContents.add(TextContent(hashtagText, TextType.hashtag));
  });

  return textContents;
}

void main() {
  String example = "Hi @BradPitt are u so cute #socute @JackieChan";
  List<TextContent> parsedText = parseText(example);

  parsedText.forEach((textContent) {
    print('text: ${textContent.text} - type: ${textContent.type}');
  });
}
```

Comment: Your "mention" pattern will not match the example given in the question: "@Brad Pitt" has a space but your pattern will stop at the first non-word character.

Comment: you are right, we always asume usernames have no white spaces in them, i assume that once a username has been identified, the UI will show the user display name instead